# Oracle gui interface for mac

Tags: oracle, user-interface, macos, ssh, client

Let me preface with saying that I'm used to using Sequel Pro on a mac for doing my database administration (table creation and inline data editing).

I have now been asked to do some oracle work as well and I'm looking for an Oracle client that has much the same feature set as Sequel Pro.

I must be able to ssh first and log into the database second. Edit data in a table view and be able to run queries easily.

The only product I've found on my own has been navicat.  However its workflow has been driving me up a wall.  :)

Any recommendations?  keeping under 500 bucks would be nice... I know about Toad but it's wickedly expensive and I'd like to hold off on asking for that if there is an adequate substitute. :)

Thank you,

-=Bryan

Answer (score 12):

[SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/index.html)... It won't do the SSH stuff natively, though. But for all the other tasks it's pretty awesome for free.